# Display 2D data in angular js from spring rest controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

I need to display data like below

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| Name | Subject1 | Subject2 | subject3 |
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| A    |       20 |       30 |       40 |
| B    |       21 |       31 |       41 |
| C    |        2 |        3 |        4 |
+------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I used spring mvc. I created a model - Student.Java

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   public class Student {
    ArrayList<String> markList;
    public ArrayList<String> getMarkList() {
     return markList;
    }
    public void setMarkList(ArrayList<String> markList) {
     this.markList = markList;
    }
   }
```

I used ResponseBody and returned List for that method. I used ajax call and got the JSON response as below

```
[{"markList":["name","subject1","subject2","subject3"]}{"markList":   ["A",20","30","40"]},{"students":["B",21","31","41"]},{"students":["C",2","3","4"]}]
```

In my Angularjs controller i just used a ajax call and assigned as below

```
var reponseData= reponse.data;
var studentarray;
var marklist;
for(var i=0;i<responseData.length;i++){
 studentarray.push(responseData[i]);
}
for(var j=0;j<studentarray.length;j++){
  marklist.push(studentarray[j].markList);
}
$scope.studentslist=marklist;
```

My jsp code
    
    
    {{col}}

But I am not getting the desired result.Can somebody help me how to design the model and access it in js. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to re-iterate an array an create a new array on the page, just directly assigns `response.data` to `studentslist`. You could just use `ng-repeat` to render a table on page.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr ng-repeat="list in studentslist">
    <td ng-repeat="mark in list.markList">{{mark}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.Now I want to apply CSS for first row alone. If I use $first , CSS is applied to first element in each row. But I want to apply CSS for all elements in first row